# I have an Opel Astra H 2008 Bluetooth adapter and need to install a power switch for it

Tags: audio, wiring, astra, bluetooth

So I have a 2008 Astra H with the default radio. I have installed a CTAVXBT001 Bluetooth kit. I want to be able to switch it on/off by adding a switch to the adaptors wire.

I have my soldering kit ready and just need to get a switch.

Which wire/s should I mount the switch on?

Link -- https://www.connects2.com/Product/ProductItem/CTAVXBT001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the switch in the power supply (+) wire.

But if there are two power wires I would not switch the one controlling the memory settings, but that would leave an albeit small energy drain.

Make sure you also fit suitable fuses.